# My FlatList does not seem to need a keyExtractor -- why?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

My FlatList does not seem to need any keyExtractor.  It works if I do not supply any keyExtractor.  It also works if I supply a keyExtractor with garbage code in it.

If I see no errors, does that mean it's safe to forgo a keyExtractor?  When do I need one?

```
_renderItem = ({item}) => (
  <Text style={styles.item}>
    {item.name[0].value}
  </Text>
)
```

And then in my render(), among other things I have...

```
<FlatList style = {styles.flatlist}
 data={this.state.data}
 renderItem={this._renderItem}
/>
```

Comment: Just for clarification, when you say you "see no errors", does that mean you see no warnings either? Not defining a `keyExtractor` will have it default to using the `index` as the key if I remember correctly. This can also be because your `data` might have a `key` prop which if defined, it would use automatically. Consider editing and adding in what data you have inside `data` to the question.

Comment: Michael, I was not seeing any warning.  But then the warning did appear the next time I worked on the project.  Not sure why the delay.  See my answer for more.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next time I worked on the project, a warning (yellow box) began to appear in the simulator.  So the keyExtractor is indeed necessary, it's just that the warning did not appear right away.

This is what made the warning go away in my case...

```
_keyExtractor = (item: { id: Array<any> }) => item.id[0].value;
```

And the item...

```
_renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <Text key={item.id[0].value} style={styles.item}>
      {item.name[0].value}
    </Text>
  )
```

And in my render function...

```
<FlatList style = {styles.flatlist}
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#keyextractor) you need a key extractor for "for caching and as the react key to track item re-ordering". You can do this by either having a key property explicitly defined for each item or by specifying an keyExtractor prop on the FlatList. If you do neither, then it will default to using the index and still work (although it will still throw an warning).

For example, let's say I have the names "Aaron", "Betty", "Charlie", and "Diane". I can do any of the following to avoid the warning:

Option 1: Key property for each item

```js
<FlatList
  data={[
      {key: 'Aaron'},
      {key: 'Betty'},
      {key: 'Charlie'},
      {key: 'Diane'}
  ]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <SomeComponent />}
/>
```

Option 2: provide keyExtractor using index

```js
<FlatList
  data = [
    {name: 'Aaron'},
    {name: 'Betty'},
    {name: 'Charlie'},
    {name: 'Dave'}
  ]
renderItem={({item}) => <SomeComponent />
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Option 3: provide keyExtractor using a specific property

```js
<FlatList
  data = [
    {name: 'Aaron'},
    {name: 'Betty'},
    {name: 'Charlie'},
    {name: 'Dave'}
  ]
renderItem={({item}) => <SomeComponent />
keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
/>
```